# Why do I have to input 3 values with this code?

Tags: c

When I run the program it forces me to input 3 values even if the third value is not used at all.

```
int main(void) {

    int var1, var2;

    printf("Enter two integers: ");

    scanf("%d \n", &var1);
    scanf("%d \n", &var2);

    printf("%d divided by %d gives %d \n", var1, var2, var1 / var2);
    printf("%d divided by %d gives remainder %d \n", var1, var2, var1 % var2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"%d \n"` wait for non-white-spaces --> `"%d"`

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf` to understand where your program fails.

Answer (score 1):

check it [scanf(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)
Be careful when using `scanf`, if you just want to get a number as input, do not place anything else in `"..."` except `%d`.

Comment: Sorta, but why are the trailing white spaces in the format string such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `scanf` consists of three parts:

- `%d`: skips as much whitespace as possible and then reads a decimal integer
- `space`: skips as much whitespace as possible
- `\n`: skips as much whitespace as possible

When you input two numbers, say `13 \n \n24\t \n`, the following happens:

- the `%d` skips the one leading space and reads the 13.
- the space after the 13 is not read yet.
- the `space` skips all whitespace, so that the input points to the 2 of 24.
- the `\n` doesn't to anything, since all whitespace has already been skipped by the .

For the second number, the same steps are done.

- the `%d` would skip any whitespace (but there is none to skip) and then read the 24.
- the `space` skips as much whitespace as possible, which in this case is `\t \n`.
- since the input is not yet at `EOF`, it waits for the next character. If that were a whitespace, it would have to be skipped. Therefore, `scanf` cannot return yet.

And that is the reason why you have to enter a third word. It doesn't have to be a number, any non-whitespace will do.

To fix this, remove the whitespace from the `scanf` format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` isn't designed to be line based, it treats all whitespace including newline equally. You could prevent the user from entering multiple numbers in the same line, which `%d%d` will accept, with the format `%d%*1[\n]`. `*` throws the value away instead of saving it to a variable, `1` reads max one character and `[\n]` reads newline characters and nothing else.

```
if (scanf("%d%*1[\n]%d%*1[\n]", &var1, &var2) != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "bad input\n");
    exit(1);
}

if (var2 == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "division by zero\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Newlines still does count as preceding whitespace though, which means this input will still be accepted:

```
3

5
```

If you want exactly two lines, nothing else, use e.g. `fgets()` and `strtol()`.